# What part of speech is the word "King" in this sentence?

Tags: parts-of-speech

The sentence I'm trying to understand is:

> King David came to battle with his army.

Is *King* an adjective or a noun? Kingly David would clearly be an adjective and "The King came to battle" would be a noun, but when used as "Title Given-Name" is the title part of the noun, a proper-noun or just an adjective?

Comment: It's better to avoid thinking of PoS "as is" and to start to consider [grammatical forms and grammatical functions](http://www.linguisticsgirl.com/grammatical-form-and-grammatical-function-a-metaphor/). The concept of PoS is very limited and potentially misleading if used heedlessly. One good example for showing its limitations is a noun pile; for example, how can we explain that these 7 nouns make up one noun phrase: [Air bag malfunction safety recall follow-up notice](http://arnoldzwicky.org/2012/01/31/noun-pile-examples/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would treat "King David" the same as I would treat "Mr. Thurston Howell III", as a proper name that happens to include an honorific.   The entire structure works as a single open-form compound word.

Answer (score 0):

king is a noun but here king functions as an adjective because it modifies David. It describes David.

Comment: Incorrect.  The earlier answer is correct in that King David is a compound noun.